# Samba NAS caching issues with IIS

Tags: nas, samba, iis, web-hosting

One of my clients uses a shared hosting account, which appears to use a Linux based NAS to host IIS content, and I'm having problems with getting it to detect file changes.

For example, once I've accessed an ASPX file from IIS, any subsequent changes to that file via FTP are ignored. Even deleting the file does nothing. IIS continues to serve it.

I've made changes in App_Code and I cannot get them to take effect. I've even tried deleting the whole App_Code folder, and IIS is obviously blissfully unaware, and continues to work as before.

Comment: Have you recycled the Application pool after posting the new code? this will cause the site to recompile. Otherwise it won't be until the next scheduled recycling (29 hour default) or WAS reactivation that the site will recompile the app_code directory, and any code-behind files. Also IIS is supposed to trigger a recompilation any time the web.config files changes (though sometimes it sticks), so try adding a space or blank line to the web.config. Since you are talking about application code, its unlikely to be IIS caching, as that happens above the asp.net runtime in IIS's HTTP features.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas Unfortunately I don't have any way to recycle the application pool. It's shared hosting with only FTP access. I tried re-uploading both the web.config and the global.asax, both of which ordinarily trigger a re-compile. It was like IIS just wasn't detecting any file changes, which led me to believe it must have been cached at the file-system level. I'm fairly sure this hosting uses a Linux based file-system via samba.

Comment: It did eventually recognise my changes. It's just very frustrating when trying to fix a bug, and having it not recognise changes when they're uploaded.

Comment: yeah, its almost impossible to host on IIS without access to the management console. perhaps consider using visual studios publishing features to precompile the site. that will ensure that it always recycles and runs the compiled code.

Comment: @FrankThomas That would still rely on IIS detecting the updated dll's. In this situation, there is just a disconnect between the filesystem as seen by IIS, and what FTP sees. The best idea, in my opinion, is to host windows content on a windows file-system. Samba is a neat utility, but it's not the same as an actual native windows file system.

Comment: it does seem like traditional windows file sharing implementations are insufficient to IIS's change detection algorithm. It appears to affect the MS implementation as well as Samba, so I wouldn't say Samba is the culprit per se. http://serverfault.com/questions/496024/why-do-microsoft-not-recommend-using-unc-paths-in-iis-what-is-the-alternative